# Build error after removing Bridging Header from Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-analytics, bridging-header

I'm trying to integrate my project from Google Analytics to Firebase Analytics. I was using Google Analytics SDK installed with Cococapods. After I do below steps;

- Remove 'GoogleAnalytics' from Pod file
- Run 'pod install'
- Remove bridging header file from the project
- Remove bridging header from build settings

I got build error with like average 300 error. Like

> Value of type 'CATransition' has no member 'fadeTransition'

I can successfully build when not uninstall Google Analytics SDK so there is no problem with my code. What can cause this problem?

**EDIT:** I found that deleting bridging header causes the problem, not the Google Analytics SDK.

Comment: I don't know why this post gets down voted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that most of my classes doesn't have `import UIKit` and somehow, when project has objective-c header, It doesn't need it. However, after I delete it, all of these classes need it. Therefore, implementing

```
import UIKit
```

fixed my problem.